# SQL data range overlap and offset

Tags: sql

I have a table like below,

```
Table 
Date1           Date2       Priority    level
1/1/1970    10/31/2013  -1  A
12/1/2013   10/31/2014  -1  A
12/31/2013  1/31/2016   1   B
12/31/2012  10/31/2018  1   C
12/31/2012  10/31/2019  2   C
12/31/2012  12/31/9999  3   C
12/31/2011  12/31/9999  4   C
```

I need to find overlap and offset date range based on level and priority.
Result

```
Date1            Date2          level
1/1/1970    10/31/2013  A
12/1/2013   10/31/2014  A
10/31/2014  1/31/2016   B
10/31/2013  12/1/2013   C
1/31/2016   10/31/2019  C
10/31/2019  12/31/9999  C
```

Visually, this will give the following:

```
A[---------]-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A----------------[-----------------]-------------------------------------------------------
B---------------------[------------------]-------------------------------------------------
C--------[----------------------------------------]----------------------------------------
C--------[-------------------------------------------------]-------------------------------
C--------[--------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
C----[------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
```

Result

```
A[---------]-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A----------------[-----------------]-------------------------------------------------------
B----------------------------------[-----]-------------------------------------------------
C----------[-----]-------------------------------------------------------------------------
C-----------------------------------------[----------------]-------------------------------
C-----------------------------------------------------------[-----------------------------]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas here. SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6acc/5

First, create a table containing two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [Map] ([Date] datetime, [Level] char(1) NULL)
```

Populate that table with something like this:

```
INSERT [Map]([Date])
SELECT Date1 FROM [Table] UNION
SELECT Date2 FROM [Table]
```

Now your [Map] table contains a list of unique dates from your original [Table]. Now it's time to find out which level each date belongs to. So you do something like:

```
UPDATE [Map] FROM [Map]
    INNER JOIN [Table] ON [Date] >= [Date1] AND [Date] < [Date2]
SET [Map].[Level] = 'A'
WHERE [Table].[Levle] = 'A' AND [Map].[Level] IS NULL
```

Repeat the above SQL for each level, B, C, and so on (maybe in a loop?). Now, your [Map] table contains the nonoverlapping intervals in prioritized order:

```
[Date]      [Level]
1/1/1970    A
12/31/2011  A
12/31/2013  A
10/31/2013  C
12/1/2013   A
12/31/2013
10/31/2014  B
1/31/2016   C
--...and so on
```

So we just have to turn this into the output form you want. We can get that by scanning through the rows of the [Map] table in [Date]-order, and noting when the [Level] changes. It can be done in a loop, but there should definitely be a nice SQL-way to do it as well, I'm just not able to wrap my head around it at the moment.